# Solution of system of $n$-linear inequations

Tags: inequality

\begin{align*} y &> c_{1}\\
 x + y &> c_{2}\\
 2x  + y &> c_{3}\\
&\phantom{\ }\vdots \\
 (n-2)x + y &> c_{n-1}\\
 (n-1)x + y &\leq c_{n}
\end{align*}

Consider $c_{1}, \cdots,c_{n}$ are constants. Can we solve this system of inequations to get single value for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Without more information about the constants $c_j$, there's no reason why the system of inequalities should have a unique solution—there could be no solution or lots of solutions. Indeed, if one finds constants such that there is a unique solution, then changing them slightly can dependably result in nonunique solutions—for instance, making $c_1,\dots,c_{n-1}$ smaller while making $c_n$ larger will change a unique solution to many possible solutions.

Comment: The only relation that we know about constants here is $c_{n} = c_{n-1} + <t>$ where t is a randomly generated number.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get range of x and y if not unique values. Appreciate your help.